# How to calculate efficiency of usable time from given Time Range in Python?

Tags: python, time

I am dealing with multiple time-range. I have to calculate efficiency(i.e. a fraction) of the usable time. This problem can be compared to any bureaucracy.

I have simply used multiple if-else statements, Is there any better way to deal with this kind of problem as code goes so long.
Inquiry Time is given as a tuple, and opening hours are given as a list of a tuple.

```
    def efficiencyRatio(inquiryTime, openingHours):
       if len(openingHours) > 1:
         ----code remain-----
       else:
         if inquiryTime[0] >= openingHours[0][0] and inquiryTime[1] <= 
         openingHours[0][1]:
             return 1

         elif inquiryTime[0] >= openingHours[0][1] or inquiryTime[1] <= 
         openingHours[0][0]:
            return 0

        elif inquiryTime[0] < openingHours[0][0] and inquiryTime[1] <= 
        openingHours[0][1]:
           totalInquiryTime = inquiryTime[1] - inquiryTime[0]
           usableInquiryTime = inquiryTime[1] - openingHours[0][0]
           efficiency = usableInquiryTime / totalInquiryTime 

       elif inquiryTime[0] >= openingHours[0][0] and inquiryTime[1] > 
       openingHours[0][1]:
          totalInquiryTime = inquiryTime[1] - inquiryTime[0]
          usableInquiryTime = openingHours[0][1] -inquiryTime[0]  
          efficiency = usableInquiryTime / totalInquiryTime

      elif inquiryTime[0] <= openingHours[0][0] and inquiryTime[1] >= 
      openingHours[0][1]:
         totalInquiryTime = inquiryTime[1] - inquiryTime[0]
         usableInquiryTime = openingHours[0][1] - openingHours[0][0]  
         efficiency = usableInquiryTime / totalInquiryTime
```

Inputs and Outputs of my problem are as follow.

```
    Inquiry Time       Opening Time        Answer
    (10, 18)       [(10, 12), (14, 16)]     0.50
    (10, 12)       [(09, 14)]               1.00
    (08, 12)       [(00, 10)]               0.50
```

Comment: Am I understanding this wrongly or what you need is the ratio between inquiry time and opening time overlapping with inquiry time. Is that correct? If so, I would split the problem in the computation of overlapping times and the total calculation.

Comment: A ratio of the usable inquiry hours to the total inquiry hours. An inquiry is only possible during the Opening hours. @norok2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it by looping over all the time slots and adding the effective hours:

```
def get_efficiency(inquiry_times, open_hours):
    usefull_hours = 0

    minimum_start_time = inquiry_times[0]
    max_end_time = inquiry_times[1]
    for times in open_hours:
        # the closing time cannot be later than the final end time
        # the start time cannot be earlier than the opening time/end of the previous time slot
        usefull_hours += min(max_end_time, times[1]) - max(minimum_start_time, times[0])
        minimum_start_time = times[1]

    total_hours = inquiry_times[1] - inquiry_times[0]

    return float(usefull_hours)/total_hours

print(get_efficiency((10, 18), [(10,12), (14, 16)]))
print(get_efficiency((10, 12), [(9, 14)]))
print(get_efficiency((8, 12), [(00, 10)]))
```

which outputs:

```
0.5
1.0
0.5
```

Do make sure your open_hours is a sorted list btw, otherwise this will mess up awfully.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood this correctly, I would simplify the code by introducing some simpler operations `overlap` to compute the overlap between two intervals and `duration` to compute the (absolute) duration of an interval.

```
def overlap(interval1, interval2):
    interval1 = sorted(interval1)
    interval2 = sorted(interval2)
    result = (
        max([interval1[0], interval2[0]]),
        min([interval1[1], interval2[1]]))
    if result[0] > result[1]:
        return (0, 0)
    else:
        return result

def duration(interval):
    return abs(interval[1] - interval[0])

def efficiency_ratio(inquiry_interval, open_intervals):
    assert(all(
        duration(overlap(interval1, interval2)) == 0
        for interval1, interval2 in itertools.combinations(open_intervals, 2)))
    effective_duration = sum([
        duration(overlap(inquiry_interval, open_interval))
        for open_interval in open_intervals])
    return effective_duration / duration(inquiry_interval)
```

Note that:
- the code has additional logic to work also for input intervals where the maximum bound is before the minimum bound.
The outputs are always with the `(min_bound, max_bound)` format.
- the `open_intervals` should be non-overlapping, and that is the meaning of the additional logic implemented inside `assert()`

To test that this work for your use case, we could do:

```
print(efficiency_ratio((10, 18), [(10,12), (14, 16)]))
# 0.5
print(efficiency_ratio((10, 12), [(9, 14)]))
# 1.0
print(efficiency_ratio((8, 12), [(0, 10)]))
# 0.5
```

EDIT: added some more input checking.